# How to hide a certain class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why this is not working. I am trying to hide a certain class and this is the only line of code I have on Javascript:

`document.getElementsByClassName("popular").style.display = "none";`

For some reason I get the error:

> "document" is not defined.

What does that mean, it's not a variable.

Please help and thank you.

Comment: are you running this in a browser?

Comment: Yes I am. It does not work either when I use getElementById and change it in the html.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of what you have please? Try reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` method returns ALL elements with the same class, think of it as an array of elements with the same class. So you need to specify, which element do you want to hide. In my example, I have only one element with such class, so I'm selecting it like the first element of an array (`[0]`). Your code should look like this:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("popular")[0].style.display = "none";

console.log('Current "display" property value is: ' + document.getElementsByClassName("popular")[0].style.display)
```

```html
<div class="popular">TARGET</div>
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to using this vs querySelectorAll? Just wondering!

Comment: @will, the OP used this way and I included it in my answer. `querySelectorAll` and `getElementsByClassName` are a little different, but I always use `getElementsByClassName`. For more info about differences, you can look through the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName and https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Somehow overlooked that hahah but thank you for the info!

Comment: @will, not at all =)